# Automate ripping TV show DVDs

Tags: macos, dvd, automation, ripping

RipIt & Handbrake do a really good job of ripping and compressing.  For normal "single main feature" DVDs I have a good workflow, and for the most part handbrake does a good job of figuring out what the main title is.

The process for ripping a DVD that has multiple episodes of something kinda sucks.  Has anyone made any progress on automating (or at least simplifying) the process of getting show-s01e01.avi from a DVD?

Comment: +1 I would love a way of speeding this up. Some of my TV shows have 20 episodes in them, it winds up keeping me house bound for a whole day just to switch discs, etc. It would be awesome to automate at least the ripping of episodes off of each disk.

Answer (score 2):

I use Handbrake and add each episode to the queue then just start the queue.  Works well for me.

Comment: that's what I do as well, but it's a pain (not hard, just a pain) to deal with mapping track to episode name/number, then correctly naming the files.  Looking for something that removes some of the suck.

Comment: With handbrake, can you put in all discs, build the queue then start at disc 1 and just swap discs when its done with a disc? That might simplify it a little. Anybody know?

Comment: Check out ripit to do the actual DVD ripping.  You can queue up jobs to do the transcoding in handbrake.  It works pretty well. Again, the issue isn't actually doing the rips/transcoding.  The issue is matching VOBs to episode number post rip/transcode.